# jquery get value out off function

Tags: jquery

```
$(".newadded").click(function () {

    var array = $('#usernames').val().split(",");
    $.each(array,function(i)
    {
        var a = (array[i]);
        if(a !="")
        {
            $('#accordian .custSecCont').show();
            uservar += "<option value='" + array[i]  + "'>" + array[i] + "</option>";  
        }


    });

});
```

I want to get uservar value in out of function.

Comment: define that variable out of function and then change it from inside function so after execution of it if you will get updated value once function execution over.

Comment: You have not declared 'uservar', declare it outside of your function as @TechnoCrat told.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uservar; // it makes uservar globally defined
$(".newadded").click(function () {
var array = $('#usernames').val().split(",");
    $.each(array,function(i)
    {
        var a = (array[i]);
        if(a !="")
        {
            $('#accordian .custSecCont').show();
            uservar += "<option value='" + array[i]  + "'>" + array[i] + "</option>";  
        }
    });
});
```